# A Stack Template

Tags: c++, beginner, reinventing-the-wheel, memory-management, stack

### Why you're here:

Today I bring you a simple Stack Machine and a ***Lot*** of questions. I am trying to gain a little bit more understanding of pointers, memory management and templates and thought a Stack implementation would be a fun exercise. As such I would love feedback pertaining to those areas, but I am of course open to any and all feedback.

### A brief description:

I've implemented a **LIFO** (Last in First Out) data structure that publicly exposes the following methods

1. Push (adds a new item to the top of the stack)
2. Pop (removes the top item from the stack (and returns the data))
3. Size (returns the size of the stack)
4. IsEmpty (returns a Boolean whether the Stack contains any Items)

---

**Stack.h**

```
#pragma once
#include <stdexcept>

template <typename T>
struct Node
{
    T data;
    Node<T>* prev{ nullptr };
};

template <typename T>
class Stack
{
public:
    Stack();
    ~Stack();

    void push(const T& rhs);

    T& pop();

    unsigned size() const noexcept;

    bool isEmpty() const noexcept;
private:
    static const unsigned max_size = 1000u;
    unsigned numElements;
    Node<T>* top;
    T returnT;
};

template<typename T>
inline Stack<T>::Stack() :
    numElements(0),
    top(nullptr) {}

template<typename T>
inline Stack<T>::~Stack()
{
    while (!isEmpty())
    {
        pop();
    }
}

template<typename T>
inline void Stack<T>::push(const T& rhs)
{
    if (numElements == 0)
    {
        top = new Node<T>;
        top->data = rhs;
        numElements++;
    }
    else if (numElements < max_size)
    {
        Node<T>* tempNode = new Node<T>;
        tempNode->data = rhs;
        tempNode->prev = top;
        top = tempNode;
        numElements++;
    }
    else
    {
        throw std::overflow_error("Stack Overflow");
    }
}

template<typename T>
inline T & Stack<T>::pop()
{
    if (numElements > 1)
    {
        returnT = top->data;
        Node<T>* tempT = top;
        top = top->prev;
        delete tempT;
        numElements--;
        return returnT;
    }
    else if (numElements > 0)
    {
        returnT = top->data;
        Node<T>* tempT = top;
        top = nullptr;
        delete tempT;
        numElements--;
        return returnT;
    }
    else
    {
        // TODO: what do I do here?
    }
}

template<typename T>
inline unsigned Stack<T>::size() const noexcept
{
    return numElements;
}

template<typename T>
inline bool Stack<T>::isEmpty() const noexcept
{
    return numElements < 1;
}
```

---

**Tests**

```
#include "Stack.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    Stack<int> IntStack;
    Stack<std::string> StringStack;

    IntStack.push(6);
    IntStack.push(-600);
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        IntStack.push(i);
    }

    StringStack.push("First Element");
    StringStack.push("Second Element");

    std::cout << IntStack.size() << "\n";
    std::cout << StringStack.size() << "\n";

    while (!IntStack.isEmpty())
    {
        int value = IntStack.pop();
        std::cout << value << "\n";
    }

    while (!StringStack.isEmpty())
    {
        std::string value = StringStack.pop();
        std::cout << value << "\n";
    }

    char delay;
    std::cin >> delay;
}
```

**Output**

> 12
>   2 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0
>   -600 6 Second Element First Element

---

### A few additional Questions:

- Is this enough functionality for a Stack? Or should I implement more functions?
- When I pop from an empty Stack I simply return nothing. Is there something else I should do?
- My IDE added `inline`. Is this actually an appropriate use?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
#pragma once
```

If you plan on writing portable code, prefer `#include` guards over `#pragma once`.  While most compilers provide support for `#pragma once`, there is no guarantee every implementation behaves the same.  Be aware of the pitfalls of `#pragma once` if you decide to use them.

---

```
    ~Stack();
```

Follow the rule of five.  If you define, `=default` or `=delete` any of the special member functions, you should consider if the behavior of the other special member functions are appropriate. In C++11, the special member functions are the destructor, copy constructor, move constructor, copy assignment operator, and move assignment operator.

```
    ~Stack();
    Stack(Stack const&);
    Stack(Stack &&);
    Stack& operator=(Stack const&);
    Stack& operator=(Stack &&);
```

You already realize that you need a destructor to clean up the `Node`s on destruction.  Do you need a user-defined copy constructor?  The copy ctor value copies your data members.  So, copying `top` only copies the pointer, not the pointed to `Node<T>`.  Copying a populated `Stack<T>` results in two stacks, both with pointers pointing at the same data.  You'll get undefined behavior when you double delete this list.

```
{
  Stack<int> s1;
  s1.push(1);
  s2.push(2);
  {
    Stack<int> s2(s1);   // Copy-construct. Fine!
    s2.pop();            // Fine!
    //auto v = s1.pop(); // double free/delete = undefined behavior, Fire everywhere
  }                      // or go out of scope with s2, destroying all data
}                        // then s1 goes out of scope... UB happens again.
```

The general advice is to avoid defining any of the special member functions if you can (rule of zero).  If you need to define any of the special member functions, then `=default`, `=delete`, or provide a user definition for them all (rule of five).

---

```
template<typename T>
inline Stack<T>::Stack() :
    numElements(0),
    top(nullptr) {}
```

When you have constant initializers, prefer the in-class initializers.

```
struct Stack {
    // Stack() = default;

private:
    unsigned numElements {0};
    Node<T>* top {nullptr};
};
```

In this context, all of your data is set to constant initializers, so you can just use the compiler generated default constructor.  You can explicitly default it (uncomment above) or implicitly default it (delete the commented line).  *Note - The default constructor is only implicitly auto-generated if there is no other user-declared constructor.*

---

```
template<typename T>
inline Stack<T>::~Stack()
{
    while (!isEmpty())
    {
        pop();
    }
}
```

In your `pop()`, you do a lot of work. `pop()` has its own boundary check (on top of the destructor boundary check), an element copy, a delete, a pointer copy, and a decrement on each call.  `~Stack()` just needs the delete and pointer copy.  Consider factoring out that portion that removes the `top` node and have both `~Stack` and `pop()` call that.

```
template <typename T>
inline void Stack<T>::unchecked_pop() {
    Node<T>* temp = top;
    top = temp-> prev;
    delete temp;
}

template<typename T>
inline Stack<T>::~Stack()
{
    while (!isEmpty())
    {
        unchecked_pop();
    }
}

template <typename T>
inline T& Stack<T>::pop() {
    if (numElements > 1) {
        returnT = top->data;
        unchecked_pop();
        num_elements--;
        return returnT;
    }
    // ...
}
```

---

Avoid calling `new` and `delete` explicitly.  In your code, you'll notice a pattern of creating a new `Node<T>` followed by copying some `T` (which could throw).

```
        Node<T>* tempNode = new Node<T>;
        tempNode->data = rhs;             // if this throws
        top = tempNode;                   // then this is never reached, memory leaks
                                          // and not cleaned up until OS reclaims
```

If you need to take ownership of a pointer, use `std::unique_ptr`/`std::make_unique`.  C++14 adds `std::make_unique`, but [you can use it C++11](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17902439/3762339).  *Note - Don't add make_unique to `std` like shown in the linked answer.*

DRY (don't repeat yourself) up your `push` and `pop`.  The two statement bodies for each function essentially does the same work.  In `push`, you trade away a pointer copy for a branch.

```
template <typename T>
inline void Stack<T>::push(const T& rhs) {
    if (numElements == max_size) {
        throw std::overflow_error("Stack Overflow");
    }

    auto temp = std::make_unique<Node<int>>();
    tempNode->data = rhs;
    tempNode->prev = top;
    top = temp.release(); // pass ownership of the new top to Stack
    numElements++;
}
```

In `pop()`, a single-element stack has a `Node` whose `prev` points to `nullptr`.  You don't need the special case for 1 element.

```
template <typename T>
inline T & Stack<T>::pop() {
    if (empty()) {
        // TODO: what do I do here?
    }

    returnT = top->data;
    unchecked_pop();
    numElements--;
    return returnT;
}
```

You don't provide any other access to `top`.  Perhaps you should just return by value?

---

> Is this enough functionality for a Stack? Or should I implement more functions?

Does it meet your needs?  At the very least, I would expect C++11 and beyond containers to support move operations (move construct, move assign, data emplacement, swap by move), comparisons, and perhaps even allocators. I would start by looking at [`std::stack`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/stack).

---

> When I pop from an empty Stack I simply return nothing. Is there something else I should do?

If you tell others "I'm returning `T&` from `pop`, it better return a `T&`.  Consider the following:

```
Stack<int> s;
auto top = s.pop(); // BOOM!
```

You could return an `optional` from `pop()`.  C++11 versions exist in [Boost](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/libs/optional/doc/html/index.html), [Abseil](https://github.com/abseil/abseil-cpp), and [Mnmlstc](https://github.com/mnmlstc/core).

Or you could do it the standard way and not return anything.  This was adopted from [SGI and annotated in their documentation](http://www.hellenico.gr/stl/stack.html):

> [3] One might wonder why `pop()` returns `void`, instead of `value_type`. That is, why must one use `top()` and `pop()` to examine and remove the top element, instead of combining the two in a single member function? In fact, there is a good reason for this design. If `pop()` returned the top element, it would have to return by value rather than by reference: return by reference would create a dangling pointer. Return by value, however, is inefficient: it involves at least one redundant copy constructor call. Since it is impossible for `pop()` to return a value in such a way as to be both efficient and correct, it is more sensible for it to return no value at all and to require clients to use `top()` to inspect the value at the top of the stack.

---

> My IDE added `inline`. Is this actually an appropriate use?

[Yes.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5131901/3762339)

---

General design notes - Utilize the adapter pattern.

I brought up the rule of zero earlier (If you can avoid defining the default operations, do).  How could we accomplish that with a `Stack`? Well, a `Stack` is an abstract data type (an interface) over a collection of data that provides operations on a single end.  The standard library provides us a bunch of collection types.  We have sequence types that have front operations (`std::deque`, `std::list`, `std::forward_list`).  We have sequence types that have back operations (`std::deque`, `std::list`, `std::vector`).

For the interface, it's very simple.  We adapt the stack interface to the interface of a container that supports modifying operations on its back.

```
template <typename T, typename Container = std::deque<T>>
struct Stack {
public:
    void push(T const& value) { data.push_back(value); }
    void pop()                { data.pop_back(); }

    T & top();                { return data.back(); }
    T const& top() const;     { return data.back(); }

    bool empty() const        { return data.empty(); }
    std::size_t size() const  { return data.size(); }

    // etc...
private:
    Container data;
};
```

*Note - Each member function should instead call a non-member free-standing function, but this review is getting pretty long and I'm trying to keep this example simple.*

By using a container type to automatically manage the memory, I don't have to provide a destructor, copy operations, or move operations.  The compiler-generated special member functions all work correct by construction.  Think about how you would implement a queue using the adapter pattern.

---

Follow-up:

> If you didn't remove the destructor would you = delete the copy constructor?

Do you want your `Stack` to be copyable? If not, they go ahead and `=delete` it.  I'm going to assume you do want a copyable `Stack`.  Since you are manually managing memory, you need to provide your own copy constructor.

```
Stack(Stack&) = default;
```

is essentially

```
Stack(Stack const& other) :
  numElements{other.numElements},
  top{other.top}, // Simple pointer copy, both stacks own same Node<T>
  returnT{other.returnT}
{}
```

Your provided copy constructor needs to deep copy every `Node` by traversing the linked list.

```
Stack(Stack const& other) :
  numElements{other.numElements},
  returnT{other.returnT}
{
    // Actually deep copy other's linked list
}
```

> If I take the return out of pop() and put it in top() I still need to deal with an empty stack. Return nothing?

It depends.  Some believe in programming-by-contract, which would require the user to ensure that the container is not empty on `pop()` and `top()`

```
T& top() const {
    return top->data; // UB if empty. User's fault for not checking size.
}
```

I would use exceptions or [`Expects()`](https://github.com/Microsoft/GSL/blob/master/include/gsl/gsl_assert) from the GSL.

```
T& top() const {
    Expects(!empty()); // if empty, either throw or fail fast
    return top->data;
}
```

You have to decide what tradeoffs you are willing to make for defined behavior and safety.

> Would a shared_ptr be needed here since Node->prev and top point to the same thing, albeit for 1 LoC?

Internally, `std::unique_ptr` would be better to represent the ownership semantics.  `Stack` is the only owner of `top`.  `top` is the only owner of the previous `Node<T>`. And so on.  Smart pointers are great for conveying ownership, but their behavior with the special members in the rule of five isn't helpful.  `std::unique_ptr` implementations still need a user-defined destructor (stack overflow from recursive destruction) and copy ops (not copyable).  `std::shared_ptr` is similar, but performs a shallow copy like the raw pointer.  I recommend Herb Sutter's talk on ["Leak-Freedom in C++... By Default"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JfmTagWcqoE).

> I also wish to say I was intentionally avoiding the STL. After all why use an underlying data structure that provides more functionality than I do when I could also just use std::stack

That's fine.  I was just pointing out how to use the adaptor pattern.  In my example, I could use any container with `push_back`, `pop_back`, etc (like [plf::list](http://plflib.org/list.htm)).

```
Stack<int, plf::list<int>> stk;
```

In your Stack, it would be better to move all of the linked list management into its own container and have Stack use that container.  That way, when you move to the next common abstract data type, a queue, you'll have a linked list container that can be reused.

Comment: Since you had a few questions, I added clarifications to the bottom of the review.

Answer (score 6):

- The `if (numElements > 1)` and `else if (numElements > 0)` differ in a single line:

  ```
      top = top->prev;
  ```

  in the former vs

  ```
      top = nullptr;
  ```

  in the latter. Try to convince yourself that the bottom element's `prev` is `nullptr` (what happens when you push an element to the empty stack?). Therefore, these two clauses shall be combined.

  The `else`, i.e. `size < 0` indicates the problem beyond your control, e.g. a badly corrupted heap, and shall throw an exception. Simply returning nothing is wrong, because it violates the declaration of the method. I wonder why you didn't get the warning.
- Similarly, there is no reason to special case of pushing into empty stack. The code from `else if` clause works verbatim.
- There is a popular school of thought claiming that `pop()` must return nothing (i.e *just* pop an element), and an access to a value must be done via a separate method (like `front()` or `peek()`). There are pros and cons to this point of view; keep in mind that STL uses this style.
- Since you limit the stack size to `max_size`, I see no reason for the overhead caused by the `prev` pointer, and dynamical allocations. A fixed size `std::vector<T>`, or `std::array<T>`, or even a plain old `T data[max_size]` array would serve the purpose in a cleaner way.

Comment: @bruglesco There are reasons to avoid naked C arrays. Once wrapped into a class, thus fully under your control, there is nothing wrong with it. Re: having max size, it is a valid design decision. Just try to avoid overhead.

Comment: @bruglescoDepends on what you call an advantage. A limited stack and unlimited stack are two different beasts, both living in their respective realms. E.g. I would never deploy an unlimited stack in the embedded system. Likely, I can happily use one in a desktop program.

Comment: Maybe you could have `peek` that returns the item and `pop` that removes the item and returns it. `pop`'s return value could just be ignored if it's not needed.

Answer (score 3):

vnp has already covered most of the big stuff, and I wholeheartedly agree with each point.

I do have a few details that I thought worth mentioning:

The `inline` and `noexcept` qualifiers seem entirely appropriate and helpful. The `const` qualifier on `size()` and `isEmpty()` is also correct, and it's good practice to think about when methods can be marked `const`. (Although it only becomes relevant with immutable objects, and the notion of an immutable stack is a very weird one to imagine!)

You can define the behaviour of class methods within the class definition. Since you're using templates and the implementation needs to go in the header anyway, it would probably be more readable to do so for at least the short methods.

`#pragma once` is widely supported but non-standard. If you want to write portable code, it's generally considered better to use include guards.

You seem to have an excessive fondness for inequalities. When you have narrowed it down to just one possible satisfying option, it is generally clearer to check equality. For example `else if (numElements == 1)` instead of `else if (numElements > 0)`.

Your `T returnT` object should not be a `stack` member variable. Just declare it in the `pop` method. In general, declaring temporary variables as local to their use as possible helps avoid bugs when they get changed, and also helps the compiler with its optimisations so you get faster code.

The memory management all looks correct to me. Everything that is manually allocated is manually deleted, and nothing is used after deletion. As already mentioned, preallocated contiguous memory generally makes for much more efficient code. Even if you wanted to get rid of the size restriction, allocating bigger chunks at a go would improve the performance. For comparison, the STL stack uses a deque rather than a list as its default underlying container.